# How do I insert todays date in Seam?

Tags: java, date, seam

I'm new to Seam and I've been searching the internet and the Seam in Action book for this, but I'm looking for way to insert today's date in a seam page  (myReport.xhtml or myPdfReport.xhtml)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a built-in component in Seam in order to get the current date.

Just put

```
#{currentDate}
```

Nothing else. You do not need to declare managed bean as @BalusC has said when using this built-in component.

Comment: I'm glad BalusC mentioned the managed-bean route because that solves other problems, but yeah, I figured there would be something like this.  And look, there it is on page 205 of Seam in Action.  So, thanks!